# Sum all tasks discount_c field with trigger code

Tags: apex, trigger

1. I added a field on the Task object - `discount_c`.
2. Account is Object & there are 4 tasks. Each task performing
   discount(Discount__c) related stuff. I want to calculate the sum of
   4 tasks. Whenever I modify a task record, the trigger should fire automatically and perform the same.
3. How can I create the trigger code for task?
4. Below is my attempt:

   ```
   trigger Task_SumOfDiscount on Account(after insert,after update){
       set<string> S1IdSet = new set<string>();
       list<Account> S1List = new list<Account>();
       list<Account> updateS1List = new list<Account>();

       (task tsk : trigger.new){
           if(string.valueof(tsk.whatid).substring(0,3) == '0012800000JNK0B'){
           }
       }

       S1List = [select id(select id,whatid,Discount__c from Tasks) from Account where id  in:  S1IdSet];

       for(Account s1: S1List){
           decimal sum = 0;
           for(task tk : s1.Tasks){
               if(tk.Discount__c != null){
                   sum += tk.Discount__c;
                   s1.Sum__c = sum;
               }
           }
           updateS1List.add(s1);
       }
       if(updateS1List.size()>0)
           update updateS1List;
   }
   ```

Comment: what is the exact question?

Comment: what does `if(string.valueof(tsk.whatid).substring(0,3) == '0012800000JNK0B'` supposed to mean?  you can't use hard-coded account ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. Trigger should be on Task not account
2. The Comparison of the What id is of the prefix to an entire ID so it will never match

   ```
   trigger Task_SumOfDiscount on Task(after insert,after update){
       set<string> S1IdSet = new set<string>();
       list<Account> updateS1List = new list<Account>();

       for(task tsk : trigger.new){
           if(tsk.whatid != null && tsk.whatid.getsObjectType() == Account.sObjectType){
               S1IdSet.add(tsk.WhatId);
           }
       }


       for(Account s1: [select id, (select id,whatid,Discount__c from Tasks) from Account where id in :S1IdSet]){
           s1.sum__c = 0;
           for(task tk : s1.Tasks){
               if(tk.Discount__c != null){
                   s1.Sum__c += tk.Discount__c;
               }
           }
           updateS1List.add(s1);
       }
       update updateS1List;
   }
   ```

Comment: getting error...expecting a right parentheses, found 'AND'

Comment: @user28787 fixed. Basic troubleshooting may be required

Comment: OP also needs to think about after delete use case as otherwise parent Account rollup will get out of sync

Comment: @cropredy - you are correct sir

Comment: why is showing error sir.......Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'select' at line 12 column 31....

Comment: @user28787 - Because I copied your query without checking it and you were missing the comma. Updated..

Comment: Sir, I have question why we are using tsk.whatid.getsObjectType()....? What line means ? Same  above  code can apply on other Sobjects in salesforce... link in Contact and Opportunity

Comment: @user28787 - It gets the type of Object the ID refers to. Documentation on the method from SF is pretty good around this area